# Root used directly doesn't work via ssh

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, sudo, root

I have a Linux system in which root is disabled by default.
I managed to enable it (`passwd root` and enabled login into root via ssh).
However, once I login into root via SSH there is nothing I can do. I get "Permission denied" to every write command I execute (i.e. `touch test`).
**However, if I login into different user (user1) with sudo privileges via SSH and do `su root` and then execute write commands, then it works perfectly fine.**
Such behaviour I find really strange and wonder how to fix it?

---

Both user1 and root have themselves as gid and same additional groups.
Both have same rights in `/etc/sudoers`

```
user1@astra-1-7-rc14:~$ id root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),109(netdev),115(lpadmin),1001(astra-admin),333(astra-console)
user1@astra-1-7-rc14:~$ id user1
uid=1000(user1) gid=1000(user1) groups=1000(user1),24(cdrom),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),109(netdev),115(lpadmin),1001(astra-admin),333(astra-console)
```

Here is sudoers file:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
%astra-admin    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Comment: Please provide OS & release details.

Comment: I do not see a problem: all you list is correct and that IS how you use SSH on Linux. "I managed to enable it (passwd root and enabled login into root via ssh)." I would revert this and keep it is as. Using sudo is a lot more Ubuntu.